# How to load more Product Cards from JSON with a nextPage attribute

Tags: javascript, html, json, fetch-api

I'm having problems nesting a fetch inside each other. I don't actually know if this is how fetch works, but my intention is to have Vanilla JavaScript to load another JSON from the nextPage url inside the JSON list, when I press the button "load more", to load more products. The json has total of 8 products, and I want to load 4 at each time I press the button.

I currently can load the 8 products from the first JSON, but when I try to load the nextPage I have an error. Is there a right way to load the nextPage and use its data?

My code so far:

```js
"use strict"

var formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('pt-BR', {
    style: 'currency',
    currency: 'BRL',
  });

fetch("http://frontend-intern-challenge-api.iurykrieger.now.sh/products?page=1")
.then(function(resp) {
    return resp.json();
})

.then(function(data) {
    var products = data.products;
    var i = 0;
    if (matchMedia('only screen and (max-width: 1000px)').matches) {
        for(i; i < 4; i++){
        let card = document.createElement('div');
        card.className = "product_card";
        card.innerHTML = `
        <img src="${products[i].image}" alt="Card de Produto">
        <div class="card_content">
            <h3>${products[i].name}</h3>
            <p>${products[i].description}</p>
            <p>De: ${formatter.format(products[i].oldPrice)}</p>
            <h4>Por: ${formatter.format(products[i].price)}</h4>
            <p>ou ${products[i].installments.count}x de ${formatter.format(products[i].installments.value)}</p>
            <button type="button" class="btn_compra">Comprar</button>
        </div>
        `
        document.getElementById('product-container').appendChild(card);
        }
        document.getElementById('button-more').addEventListener('click', () => {
            if(i == 4) {
                for(i; i < 8; i++){
                    let card = document.createElement('div');
                    card.className = "product_card";
                    card.innerHTML = `
                    <img src="${products[i].image}" alt="Card de Produto">
                    <div class="card_content">
                        <h3>${products[i].name}</h3>
                        <p>${products[i].description}</p>
                        <p>De: ${formatter.format(products[i].oldPrice)}</p>
                        <h4>Por: ${formatter.format(products[i].price)}</h4>
                        <p>ou ${products[i].installments.count}x de ${formatter.format(products[i].installments.value)}</p>
                        <button type="button" class="btn_compra">Comprar</button>
                        </div>
                    `
                    document.getElementById('product-container').appendChild(card);
                    }
                    i = 0;
            } else if(i == 0) {
                fetch(data.nextPage)
                .then(function(resp) {
                        return resp.json();
                    })
                .then(function(data) {
                    products = data.products;
                })
                for(i; i < 4; i++){
                    let card = document.createElement('div');
                    card.className = "product_card";
                    card.innerHTML = `
                    <img src="${products[i].image}" alt="Card de Produto">
                    <div class="card_content">
                        <h3>${products[i].name}</h3>
                        <p>${products[i].description}</p>
                        <p>De: ${formatter.format(products[i].oldPrice)}</p>
                        <h4>Por: ${formatter.format(products[i].price)}</h4>
                        <p>ou ${products[i].installments.count}x de ${formatter.format(products[i].installments.value)}</p>
                        <button type="button" class="btn_compra">Comprar</button>
                    </div>
                    `
                    document.getElementById('product-container').appendChild(card);
                }
            }
        })

    } else {
        for(let i = 0; i < 8; i++){
            let card = document.createElement('div');
            card.className = "product_card";
            card.innerHTML = `
            <img src="${products[i].image}" alt="Card de Produto">
            <div class="card_content">
                <h3>${products[i].name}</h3>
                <p>${products[i].description}</p>
                <p>De: ${formatter.format(products[i].oldPrice)}</p>
                <h4>Por: ${formatter.format(products[i].price)}</h4>
                <p>ou ${products[i].installments.count}x de ${formatter.format(products[i].installments.value)}</p>
                <button type="button" class="btn_compra">Comprar</button>
            </div>
            `
            document.getElementById('product-container').appendChild(card);
        }
    }
});
```

I'm getting this Error Message
[image: Error Message]

***UPDATED***
That's what I came up with:

```js
"use strict"

var formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('pt-BR', {
    style: 'currency',
    currency: 'BRL',
  
    // These options are needed to round to whole numbers if that's what you want.
    //minimumFractionDigits: 0, // (this suffices for whole numbers, but will print 2500.10 as $2,500.1)
    //maximumFractionDigits: 0, // (causes 2500.99 to be printed as $2,501)
  });

fetch("http://frontend-intern-challenge-api.iurykrieger.now.sh/products?page=1")
.then(function(resp) {
    return resp.json();
})
.then(function(data) {
    var jsonNextPage = data.nextPage; //Store the nextPage
    var products = data.products;
    console.log(products);
    console.log(data);
    var i = 0;
    if (matchMedia('only screen and (max-width: 1000px)').matches) {
        for(i; i < 4; i++){
        let card = document.createElement('div');
        card.className = "product_card";
        card.innerHTML = `
        <img src="${products[i].image}" alt="Card de Produto">
        <div class="card_content">
            <h3>${products[i].name}</h3>
            <p>${products[i].description}</p>
            <p>De: ${formatter.format(products[i].oldPrice)}</p>
            <h4>Por: ${formatter.format(products[i].price)}</h4>
            <p>ou ${products[i].installments.count}x de ${formatter.format(products[i].installments.value)}</p>
            <button type="button" class="btn_compra">Comprar</button>
        </div>
        `
        document.getElementById('product-container').appendChild(card);
        }
        document.getElementById('button-more').addEventListener('click', () => {
            if(i == 4) {
                for(i; i < 8; i++){
                    let card = document.createElement('div');
                    card.className = "product_card";
                    card.innerHTML = `
                    <img src="${products[i].image}" alt="Card de Produto">
                    <div class="card_content">
                        <h3>${products[i].name}</h3>
                        <p>${products[i].description}</p>
                        <p>De: ${formatter.format(products[i].oldPrice)}</p>
                        <h4>Por: ${formatter.format(products[i].price)}</h4>
                        <p>ou ${products[i].installments.count}x de ${formatter.format(products[i].installments.value)}</p>
                        <button type="button" class="btn_compra">Comprar</button>
                        </div>
                    `
                    document.getElementById('product-container').appendChild(card);
                    }
                    i = 0;
            } else if(i == 0) {
                
                fetch('http://' + jsonNextPage) //use var nextPage
                .then(function(resp) {
                        return resp.json();
                    })
                .then(function(data) {
                    jsonNextPage = data.nextPage; //immediately store the updated nextPage to the variable
                    products = data.products;
                for(i; i < 4; i++){
                    let card = document.createElement('div');
                    card.className = "product_card";
                    card.innerHTML = `
                    <img src="${products[i].image}" alt="Card de Produto">
                    <div class="card_content">
                        <h3>${products[i].name}</h3>
                        <p>${products[i].description}</p>
                        <p>De: ${formatter.format(products[i].oldPrice)}</p>
                        <h4>Por: ${formatter.format(products[i].price)}</h4>
                        <p>ou ${products[i].installments.count}x de ${formatter.format(products[i].installments.value)}</p>
                        <button type="button" class="btn_compra">Comprar</button>
                    </div>
                    `
                    document.getElementById('product-container').appendChild(card);
                }
            })
        }
    })

    } else {
        for(let i = 0; i < 8; i++){
            let card = document.createElement('div');
            card.className = "product_card";
            card.innerHTML = `
            <img src="${products[i].image}" alt="Card de Produto">
            <div class="card_content">
                <h3>${products[i].name}</h3>
                <p>${products[i].description}</p>
                <p>De: ${formatter.format(products[i].oldPrice)}</p>
                <h4>Por: ${formatter.format(products[i].price)}</h4>
                <p>ou ${products[i].installments.count}x de ${formatter.format(products[i].installments.value)}</p>
                <button type="button" class="btn_compra">Comprar</button>
            </div>
            `
            document.getElementById('product-container').appendChild(card);
        }
        
        document.getElementById('button-more').addEventListener('click', () => {
            fetch('http://' + jsonNextPage) //Same as before
            .then(function(resp) {
                return resp.json();
            })
            .then(function(data) {
                jsonNextPage = data.nextPage; //Same as before
                products = data.products;            
                for(let i = 0; i < 8; i++){
                let card = document.createElement('div');
                card.className = "product_card";
                card.innerHTML = `
                <img src="${products[i].image}" alt="Card de Produto">
                <div class="card_content">
                    <h3>${products[i].name}</h3>
                    <p>${products[i].description}</p>
                    <p>De: ${formatter.format(products[i].oldPrice)}</p>
                    <h4>Por: ${formatter.format(products[i].price)}</h4>
                    <p>ou ${products[i].installments.count}x de ${formatter.format(products[i].installments.value)}</p>
                    <button type="button" class="btn_compra">Comprar</button>
                </div>
                `
                document.getElementById('product-container').appendChild(card);
                }
            })
        })
    }
})
```

Comment: What happens when you do: `fetch('http://' + data.nextPage)` ?

Comment: @Daantje I can finally get the nextPage and show the new products from page 2 , but I will have to figure out how to continuously update the data after every new fetch, how do I continuously get the next page, updating the response from fetch.

Comment: Make the calback of the click on `#button-more` a separate function, and call that function at the end of that function. That way it's going to loop... I don't want to rewrite your code, because it looks like a challenge you have to finish. So you have to check how to do that your self ;)

Comment: It's cool, I think I figured out what to do, when I come up with the solution I will let you know.

Comment: Somehow I made it work :)) I will edit my question update the difference I made.
But could you explain me how to use callback functions in this case? I'm sure it would make my code be cleaner, or wait until tuesday, my challenge is until tomorrow haha

Comment: Use the DRY principle. Don't Repeat Yourself... When code is duplicated, you should make it a separate `function doSomething(variables){ //some code}`, and call that function like `doSomething(123);` so it executes the code. This is basic programming... With the event listners you could do `addEventListener('click', doSomeClick);`. and `function doSomeClick(event){ console.log(event);}`.

Comment: You could write `.then(function(data) {` as `.then(parseData)`. And the function declaration is like: `function parseData(data){ //rest of code`.

Comment: And? How was your test?

Comment: Well, I still haven't got the answer yet, but overall I think my code was good, at least for a Entry Level one, I know I still got a lot to learn, mainly in terms of clean code, DRY and SOLID fundamentals, and I just started learning React (just now tbh).
My repository for the project I sent to the test review is here: https://github.com/tobiasorosa/linx-challenge
If you got any tips for a wannabe junior dev, just give it to me, please =)
And I appreciate the help though

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `nextPage` property does not contain a protocol. Instead it looks something like this:
`frontend-intern-challenge-api.iurykrieger.now.sh/products?page=2`

When you fetch such an URL your browser will interpret it as a relative path append it to the current one which is localhost in your case. You need to prepend `http://` here when fetching the next page.

```
fetch('http://' + data.nextPage)
```

Comment: I successfully got to the nextPage with that, but there is some mistake in my logic, because the Data is only getting updated to the 2nd page, not beyond (this API has infinite JSON apparently)